# Почему код выполняется сразу а не при соблюдении условия onblur

Tags: javascript

Есть простой код

```
document.getElementById('enter_name').onblur = alert('hello');
```

То есть при потере фокуса инпута enter_name должен выводиться alert с надписью hello. Но проблема в том что alert выполняется сразу же при загрузке страницы. Почему так?

Comment: Потому что `alert("...")` — это вызов функции, который сразу выполняется и возвращает undefined, который записывается в свойство `onblur`. А туда надо присвоить функцию, которая будет вызываться при событии... т.е. `.onblur = function(){ alert('bubu') };`

Comment: Выбивает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onblur' of null
    at js_2.js:4

Comment: Cкрипт загружается раньше, чем HTML) Надо перенести его в конец...

Comment: `document.getElementById('enter_name').onblur= function(){
  alert("1")
}`

Comment: Quazimorda та же самая ошибка.

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME он и так в конце body, поэтому я и не понимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: @Виталий, покажите фрагмент кода.

Comment: @Quazimorda скинул в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Даже при таком оформлении все равно ошибка.

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('enter_name').onblur= function(){ alert("1") };
}
```

Ниже весь HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Монализа</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="enter_text" name="enter_text">
   <img src="./img/game_1/zero.jpg" id="mona">
   <div id="div"> <p><span>Теставая запись.</span></p></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/js_2.js"></script>
</body>
```

P.S Ошибка была в том что отсутствовал объект с необходимым id. По невнимательности вместо enter_text написал enter_name

Comment: А где у вас элемент с id="enter_name"?

Comment: ахахаахах ё-маё, вот это стыдобища!!! аахаахах Дааааа уж. Сорри. Походу пора сделать паузу и отдохнуть немного, в элементарных вещах ошибки делаю. )))